# How to get count of each item in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have csv where it reads transaction like as follows

Diaper Cola Paste

Diaper Cola Pen

I would like to get the count of each transaction items as follows:

Diaper:1 Cola:1 Paste:1

Diaper:1 Cola:1 Pen:1

The code i tried is :

```
from collections import Counter

def M():
    list=[]
    DataCaptured= csv.reader(Datafile,delimiter=" ")
    for row in DataCaptured:
        list.append(row)
    Counter(list)
```

I am getting list is unhashable error.

Comment: Can you explain your output?

Comment: I only see one diaper in the first transaction. In the output, you have the diaper count at 2. Where did you get 2 from? Is it supposed to be an input of `Diaper Cola Diaper Paste` becomes `Diaper:2 Cola:1 Paste:1`?

Comment: @ToothpickAnemone sorry it was a mistake Diaper count is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues/fixed in your code

- Don't use python built-in keywords like `list` for your list variable, use some other name e.g `li`
- You want to pass a file object to [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader), and not the name of the file
- You want to append the `Counter` on each row in a single list via `li.append(row)`

Once we have this fixes, the code changes to

```
from collections import Counter
import csv

def M():
    li=[]
    #Open the csv file
    with open('file.txt') as fp:
        DataCaptured = csv.reader(fp,delimiter=' ')
        #Iterate throught each word in csv and add it's counter to the row
        for row in DataCaptured:
            li.append(dict(Counter(row)))
    #Return the list of counters
    return li

print(M())
```

The output will be

```
[{'Diaper': 1, 'Cola': 1, 'Paste': 1}, 
{'Diaper': 1, 'Cola': 1, 'Pen': 1}]
```

Comment: Is it possible that i can get for each row? As mentioned above, Now you are getting count of all diapers. But i want for each row and their count

Comment: I have updated the answer @KSp Please take a look and let me know any questions you have :)

Comment: The code gives a count for each letter but i want each word.

Comment: Thanks for the accept @KSp but I have reverted your question to the previous edit of to avoid confusion for other readers and answerers, also you can ask for any issues in the code directly here, you don't need to update the question for the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Append a (hashable) tuple, instead:

```
        list.append(tuple(row))
```